# How do I download one or more files from a stopped Fargate task?

Tags: aws-fargate

I have an ECS task that runs some test cases.  I have it running in Fargate.  Yay!

Now I want to download the test results file(s) from the container.  I have the task and container IDs handy.  I can find the exit code with

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster Fargate --tasks <my-task-id>
```

How do I download the log and/or files produced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, as of right now, the only way to get test results off of my server is to send the results to S3 before the container shuts down.

From [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=822892), there's no way to mount a volume / EFS onto a Fargate container.

Here's my bash script for running my tests (in build.sh) and then uploading the results to S3:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Running tests...

pushd ~circleci/project/
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_KEY

commandToRun="~/project/.circleci/build_scripts/build.sh";

# Run the command
eval $commandToRun 2>&1 | tee /tmp/build.log

# Get the exit code
exitCode=$?

aws s3 cp /tmp/build-$FEATURE.log s3://$CICD_BUCKET/build.log \
    --storage-class REDUCED_REDUNDANCY \
    --region us-east-1

exit ${exitCode}
```

Of course, you'll have to pass in the AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY and CICD_BUCKET environment variables. The bucket name you choose needs to be pre-created, but any directory structure below it does NOT need to be created in advance.

Comment: If you're using ECS or Fargate, you can assign an IAM role to the task instead of passing in credentials.  Documentation about IAM roles for tasks is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html

Comment: And if you REALLY need to get environmental variables inside an ECS Fargate Task, you should use the credentials variable in the container_properties definition, as it is said in this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_RegisterJobDefinition.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at using CodeBuild for this use case, which can automatically copy artifacts to S3.

It's actually quite easy to orchestrate the following using a simple bash script and the AWS CLI:

- Idempotently Create/Update a CodeBuild project (using a simple CloudFormation template you can define in your source repository)
- Run a Codebuild job that executes a given revision of your source repository (using again a self-defining buildspec.yml specification defined in your source repository)
- Attach to the CloudWatch logs log group for your CodeBuild job and stream log output
- Finally detect when the job has completed successfully or not and then download any artifacts locally using S3

I use this approach to run builds in CodeBuild, with Bamboo as the overarching continuous delivery system.